# Can't export Blender model for use in jMonkeyEngine SDK

Tags: ogre, blender, jmonkeyengine

I have a scene rendered in blender called "civ1.blend" which contains multiple materials (for example, I have one called "white"). I want to use this model in jMonkeyEngine, so I used the OGRE exporter to create .scene and .material files. This gives me, for example, a civ1.scene file and a white.material file.
However, when I then try to import civ1.scene into the jMonkeyEngine SDK, I get an error along the lines of "Cannot find material file 'civ1.material'". Like I said, I have a white.material file, but I do not have a civ1.material file. Did anyone encounter this problem? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who had the same problem I did, where you've installed the OGRE exporter in Blender 2.6 but still don't get .material files, the reason for this is in the configurations. When you are in the export menu (File > Export > Ogre3D), in the lower-left corner there are configurations. By default, "Separate Materials" is checked. Uncheck this and you're ready to go!